# Change Button depending on Data from different window

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm currently trying to create a reservation application that resembles a cinema. I'm having some issues handling the reservation as i created a 5x5 grid of buttons which calls a seperate window. In that window you can enter a name and the movie you want to see. Afterwards the button should be colored in a different color to show that this place has already been reservated.

I was able to generate the buttons and each button calls a new window. However i can't seem to figure out how to pass the name and movie information back to the button to configure it. Also, wouldn't it color in all my buttons the way i created them, since they all are basically the "same" object? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code Buttongrid:

```
public partial class Filmgrid : Window
{
    public Filmgrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int width = 5;
        int height = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            var rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            var columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                ResButton b = new ResButton(); //selfmade buttons
                grid.Children.Add(b);
                Grid.SetColumn(b, i);
                Grid.SetRow(b, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code ResButton:

```
public partial class ResButton : UserControl
{
    public ResButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResWindow ResWindow = new ResWindow();
        ResWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Code ResWindow:

```
public partial class ResWindow : Window
{
    public ResWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send Data to Filmgrid Window to change button
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe is not what you want but.. why don't you have a representation place to print the available seats and set there a refresh mechanism (or a publish-subscribe pattern) and you skip the generation of too many buttons and the complexity that is adding this to your project?

Comment: @FedericoJoséSorenson sounds good but don't i need to have buttons so i can call a new window? So i would need to have a new class with width and height that also creates a button? sorry i'm fairly new to wpf

Comment: No problem @Byakko_Hakyu, when you open the second window, and then you reserve the seat, in that moment you have the possibility of re-rendering the panel you have. 

you can use the UpdateLayout() method on your Window class for that 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However i can't seem to figure out how to pass the name and movie information back to the button to configure it.

As a quick fix, you could create public properties on `ResWindow` with the appropriate information:

```
public partial class ResWindow : Window {
  public string PersonName {get; set;}
  public string MovieName {get; set;}

  public ResWindow() => InitializeComponent();

  private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.Close();

  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    PersonName = txbPersonName.Text;
    MovieName = txbMovieName.Text;
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Then, in `ResButton`, you can handle the [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event, and retrieve the data before the window closes:

```
public partial class ResButton : UserControl {
  public ResButton() => InitializeComponent();

  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ResButton btn = sender as ResButton;
    ResWindow ResWindow = new ResWindow();
    ResWindow.Closing += (s1, e1) => {
      ResWindow win = s1 as ResWindow;
      //do something here with ResWindow.PersonName and ResWindow.MovieName
      //you can access the btn variable here as well
    };
    ResWindow.Show();
  }
}
```

---

> Also, wouldn't it color in all my buttons the way i created them, since they all are basically the "same" object?

No, because each time you call `new ResButton();`, you are creating a new `ResButton`. If your problem is that you don't have a way to refer to each `ResButton`, there are two solutions:

1. The convention in .NET is that the first parameter to an event handler is the object which raised the event. In this case, the first parameter to the `Click` event will be the button that was clicked.
2. Alternatively, you can hold references to all the buttons in some kind of `List<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` which you declare on the `Filmgrid` window.